# Any QR barcode generator open source for iPhone?

Tags: generator, barcode, qr-code

ZXing and Zbar can be QR scanner, so what are the open source project for generator for iPhone ?

Comment: Any luck ?? Even i am also looking for it.

Comment: Looking for the same thing. I am using Google Charts API at the moment but I need something that doesn't require internet connection. May I suggest you add a tag "iPhone" to the question? You may get more exposure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZXing has a QR code generator inside its main Java code, in the core/ module, package `com.google.zxing.qrcode.encode`. It's not ported to C++, but I think you'll find it pretty easy to port.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following two

https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator

OR

https://github.com/jverkoey/ObjQREncoder

Comment: I'm having a trouble using kuapay. it generates fine for the first time. but if i try to regenerate without closing the app. then the app crashes automatically. Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: @dinesh Sorry I no longer use kuapay. Did you try ObjQREncoder?

Comment: I dont know how to execute the ObjQREncoder. anyhow I have fixed the bug in kuapay. you need to remove the autorelease in filemanager.m. Now its working fine for everytime I generate. Thanks